# Creating manytomany objects on a fresh django db object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django-rest-framework and am trying to add tags to my models.
Every thing is ready on the database-side, but how do I do it on the django-rest side?

Simplified, my model looks like:

```
name = models.CharField()
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

I am presenting the tags as a comma-list in django-rest to make it easy for people using the API to add and change tags. However, how can I add tags to a object that doesn’t exists yet?

Using django-rest restore_object in my serializer, I am able to create the list of manytomany objects, but how do I add them to django-rest attrs so it will add them to my object?

In short, how can I add a list of items to .tags in django-rest restore_object function?

Or is this impossible and I need to do the tags handeling -after- the object is created and therefor hide the "tags" field when creating the object in django-rest and display it at the detailed serializer page instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best method, but this seems to work with overriding the save_object method in the serializer.

```
def save_object(self, obj, **kwargs):
    super(MySerializer, self).save_object(obj, **kwargs)

    tags = self.init_data.get('tags', None)
    if tags:
        obj.tags.clear()
        tags = tags.split(',')
        for t in tags:
            tag_obj, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=t, owner=self.context['request'].user)
            obj.tags.add(tag_obj)
```

Is it a bad idea to grab this data from init_data? Seems a little dirty...